# Where to update git credentials in fastlane

Tags: git, fastlane

I'm setting up Fastlane on a new Xcode Server. Part of this process involves a push to a remote git repo which currently fails due to missing credentials.

Where do I set the credentials for Fastlane to access and push our version bump?

For reference I've added the logs below:

```
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:18.91]: [32m--------------------------------[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:18.91]: [32m--- Step: push_to_git_remote ---[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:18.91]: [32m--------------------------------[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:18.92]: [36m$ pwd[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:18.93]: ▸ [35m/Users/me/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/9c9497a3d0dbcfc749289c0861016c7f/Source/app[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:18.93]: [36m$ git push origin branch:branch --tags[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:19.03]: ▸ [35mfatal: could not read Username for 'https://mygithub.com': Device not configured[0m
WARN [2019-03-15 12:23:19.03]: [33m[33mLane Context:[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:19.03]: {:PLATFORM_NAME=>nil, :LANE_NAME=>"after_integration", :VERSION_NUMBER=>"1.-", :BUILD_NUMBER=>"2"}
ERROR [2019-03-15 12:23:19.03]: [31mExit status of command 'git push origin branch:branch --tags' was 128 instead of 0.
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://mygithub.com': Device not configured
[0m
INFO [2019-03-15 12:23:19.04]: [32mSuccessfully generated documentation at path '/Users/me/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/9c9497a3d0dbcfc749289c0861016c7f/Source/app/fastlane/README.md'[0m

+------+---------------------+-------------+
|             [32mfastlane summary[0m             |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action              | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1    | get_version_number  | 1           |
| 2    | get_build_number    | 0           |
| 3    | commit_version_bump | 2           |
|    | [31mpush_to_git_remote[0m  | 0           |
+------+---------------------+-------------+

ERROR [2019-03-15 12:23:19.04]: [31mfastlane finished with errors[0m
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really a git question, not a fastlane question. All fastlane does is run the git command.

Looks like you are using an `https://` git URL, which means you need to set up the git credential helper to retrieve your password from the macOS keychain. https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git. Once the password is saved the fastlane action will complete successfully.